# MySQL - 2 way query check

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am implementing "**Add Friend**" in my web app, so users could add other users as fiends.

We have 2 tables: **tbl_users** and **tbl_relations**, tbl_users have an unique ID for the registered users and tbl_relations will store the users which are friends, for example some rows in tbl_relations are:

```
id     user_id_1     user_id_2
1      4             6
2      4             8
3      8             23
4      12            84
5      3             4
...
```

In the above results, the id is the unique id for the tbl_relations, user_id_1 is foreign key to tbl_users and user_id_2 is foreign key to tbl_users, now imagine we want to query and check if user with id "4" is friend with user with id "9" or not, here we need to send the query in 2 ways, I mean:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_relations WHERE (user_id_1 = '4' AND user_id_2 = '9') OR (user_id_1 = '9' AND user_id_2 = '4')
```

The above query seems a little weird to me, there should be another way for implementing this I guess, maybe a different database structure?

Or another query, we want to get the **mutual friends** between users with id "4" and "8", how I'm supposed to get the mutual friends in this scenario? is there any better database structure for this?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would de-normalize the relation such that it's symmetric. That is, if 1 and 2 are friends, i'd have two rows (1,2) and (2,1).

The disadvantage is that it's twice the size, and you have to do 2 writes when forming and breaking friendships. The advantage is all your read queries are simpler. This is probably a good trade-off because most of the time you are reading instead of writing.

This has the added advantage that if you eventually outgrow one database and decide to do user-sharding, you don't have to traverse every other db shard to find out who a person's friends are.

Comment: Is this how other big companies implemented this? I mean Facebook, G+, linked in..., I don't think so! how about the Mutual Friends? thanks

Comment: Facebook implements it like this, though most operations are not done on the db servers because it doesn't scale. Mutual friends can be done by intersecting the friend rows of both users. If you want to do it as a single query: `SELECT * FROM tbl_relations AS a INNER JOIN tbl_relations AS b ON a.user_id_2 = b.user_id_2 WHERE a.user_id_1 = '4' AND b.user_id_1 = '9'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it this way you'll have to check for duplicates every time you update. Why not have

> user_id1     friend_id

and then query as

> select * from tbl_relations where user_id1 in (4,9)

This still seems odd at it implies that 'friend' relations are one-way.

To get the 'mutual' friends - if you do it this way -

> select * from tbl_relations t0
>       join tbl_relations t1 on t0.friend_id = t1.friend_id
>       where t0.user_id1 = ? and t1.user_id1 = ?

Comment: I don't get how this answer solves the 2 way check, would you please explain more? thanks

Comment: It's querying for two `user_ids` that have the same friends. Its in 'prepared statement' format.

Comment: the query `select * from tbl_relations where user_id1 in (4,9)` is wrong, this will return all the records which user_id1 = 4 OR user_id1 = 9, obviously, this could not determine if 2 users are friends or not!

Comment: Not if the relationship was two-way. If it remains one-way, then yes you are right.

Comment: of course the relation ship of friends is 2-way, while A is friends with B, so B is friends with A, still, we could not check if A and B are friends or not with your suggested query, please explain more. thanks