# Checking users friendship

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Continuing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933248/mysql-2-way-query-check/),

in my web app, I want to allow users to add friends, like facebook, in my previous question, I finally decided to have the database structure as @yiding said:

> I would de-normalize the relation such that it's symmetric. That is,
>   if 1 and 2 are friends, i'd have two rows (1,2) and (2,1).
>
> The disadvantage is that it's twice the size, and you have to do 2
>   writes when forming and breaking friendships. The advantage is all
>   your read queries are simpler. This is probably a good trade-off
>   because most of the time you are reading instead of writing.
>
> This has the added advantage that if you eventually outgrow one
>   database and decide to do user-sharding, you don't have to traverse
>   every other db shard to find out who a person's friends are.

So, now if user 1 adds user 2, and user 5 adds 2, something like this will go into the db:

```
ROW_ID    USER_ID   FRIEND_ID   STATUS
1         1         2           0
2         2         1           0
3         5         2           0
4         2         5           0
```

As you see, we insert the row of the "**REQUEST SENDER**" first, so now imagine that user `5` is logged in, and we want to show him the friendship requests, here is my query:

```
$check_requests = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends_tbl WHERE FRIEND_ID = '5'");
```

the above query, will fetch ROW_ID = 4, this means with the above query shows us that user 2 has added 5, but he has NOT, actually the user 5 added user 2, so here we should not show any friendship requests for user 5, instead we need to show it for user 2.

How I'm supposed to check this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is an edited answer.*

---

Your SQL query should look like this:

```
SELECT USER_ID, FRIEND_ID FROM friends_tbl WHERE FRIEND_ID = '5' OR USER_ID = '5'
```

Then you have to parse your result in this way. Assuming you have got a php array like this:

```
$result = array(
    0 => array(
        'USER_ID' => 5,
        'FRIEND_ID' => 2
    ),
    1 => array(
        'USER_ID' => 2,
        'FRIEND_ID' => 5
    )
    2 => array(
        'USER_ID' => 5,
        'FRIEND_ID' => 8
    ),
    3 => array(
        'USER_ID' => 8,
        'FRIEND_ID' => 5
    )
)
```

You just have to get the even rows:

```
$result_final = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    if($i % 2 == 0) $result_final[] = $result[$i];
}
```

Then you will have an array like this:

```
    $result = array(
    0 => array(
        'USER_ID' => 5,
        'FRIEND_ID' => 2
    ),
    1 => array(
        'USER_ID' => 5,
        'FRIEND_ID' => 8
    )
)
```

---

**Alternative method:** Make your SQL look like this:

```
SELECT FRIEND_ID FROM friends_tbl WHERE USER_ID = '5'
```

That's all.

Comment: this doesn't help my question!

Comment: OK. I read it twice and not I understand what you mean. If user 5 adds user 2 as a friend, is it saved in the DB as the first row (I mean 5->2 is before 2->5)?

Comment: thanks for the answer, the alternative method won't work, but the main one will work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Friendship query notifies should be placed in something like message inbox. Relation you described is meant to hold, well, friendship relations, not the fact of the event happening itself. You should consider create relation to hold notifies and fill it properly alongside with two inserts on `friends_tbl`

Comment: You mean I need to have another table for loading notifications!? it came to my mind but ina second though, I found this useless since that table is going to be checked WITH friends_tbl while we want to check which users COULD send friends requests

Comment: @behz4d yes, I meant another table for notifications. And this table is not meant to be checked on a user login, something like this should do the trick: `select * from notification where user like x and unread=true`, where x is logged in user' id.

Comment: @HЛО The only reason that I did not do this is: now imagine users are in the website, one wants to add another user, now for checking if this user COULD add this user as friend or not, we need to check 2 tables! first one is the friends_tbl, which holds the added friends, then the notifications table, so if he already sent the friend request, we should not allow him to send another one, that's why I implemented this like the mentioned..., any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hold a temporary table (or fixed - for data mining) which has all the requests made from one user to another, for example:

table: friendRequest

```
inviterId inviteeId status tstamp 
    2           5       0    NOW()
    5           8       0    NOW()
```

assuming that 0 is unapproved.

Than you'll query for all pending requests

```
SELECT * FROM friendRequest WHERE invitee_id = :currentLoggedUserId AND status = 0
```

Once a user approved a user, you'll create a transaction, describing this newly formed relation and updating the friendRequests table

You could also query this way assymetric relations, where a user has many followers, by looking for un-mutual friendships.